# How to give same number if it exist on table or new number if it not exist based on part value?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, window-functions

I work on sql server 2019 i have table `#parts` have group of numbers on Part Value Field .

my issue how to give unique number to every group of numbers on Part Value Field

if group numbers on part Value not exist before on table then it will take new number.

if group numbers on part Value exist on table it will give same number that exist per group on table .

**original table as below :**

```
 create table #parts
      (
      PartNumber varchar(50),
      PartValue int,
      UniqueNumber int
      )
      insert into #parts(PartNumber,PartValue,UniqueNumber)
      values
      ('P1',1,NULL),
      ('P1',2,NULL),
      ('P1',3,NULL),
      ('P1',4,NULL),
      ('P2',1,NULL),
      ('P2',2,NULL),
      ('P3',1,NULL),
      ('P3',2,NULL),
      ('P3',3,NULL),
      ('P4',1,NULL),
      ('P4',2,NULL),
      ('P4',3,NULL),
      ('P5',1,NULL),
      ('P5',2,NULL)
```

i need to give every similar part value same number on unqiue number

this is exactly what i need

so please how to solve it without using stuff numbers or string aggregate ?

**i don't need to use logic below because it will performance issue for big count**

expected result as below

[image: image show result i need]

may be using string aggregte or stuff as 1,2,3 or 1,2 or 1,2,3,4 and give every group of numbers unqiue number .

to get different between every group

but i don't need to use this logic by stuff or string aggregte

Notes : this solve my issue and give me result expected

```
SELECT
  p.PartNumber,
  p.PartValue,
  p2.Parts,
  NewUniqueNumber = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY p2.Parts)
FROM #parts p
JOIN (
    SELECT
      p2.PartNumber,
      STRING_AGG(p2.PartValue, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p2.PartValue) Parts
    FROM #parts p2
    GROUP BY
      p2.PartNumber
) p2 ON p2.PartNumber = p.PartNumber;
```

result as expected

but i need another solutions if possible
for good performance without using stuff or string aggreagte
i need another idea

Comment: I don't understand the new logic: why do `P4` values get `3` and `P5` values get `2`?

Comment: I give number of unique number based on part value so if part value 1,2,3 and take unique value 3 so if it repated again 1 ,2,3 then it will take 3

Comment: if not clear i can mention more

Comment: number of unique number generated not important for me . the most important for me is if part value 1,2,3 then it must take same number if 1,2,3 again repated for another partnumber and if part value 1,2 then it will take another number different

Answer (score 2):

***Due to post-facto changes to the original question, this answer is not completely relevant. I will leave it here anyway.***

You don't need a separate column for this (which would require extra maintenance using trigger etc to keep up to date).

Instead just use `DENSE_RANK` when you query the table

```sql
SELECT *,
  NewUniqueNumber = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PartNumber)
FROM #parts p
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2a942bc2fcb839036a33ec496a8edf95)

Comment: thank you for reply i need unique number based on partvalue not part number so this answer will not give  me correct result

Comment: It matches your original question, rather than your new version with unclear logic

Answer (score 2):

**You changed the requirements after I created my previous answer. Here is a new answer based on the new requirements.**

You can group up the rows and aggregate all `PartValue`s using `STRING_AGG`. Then re-join it back to the original table, and use `DENSE_RANK`  over that aggregation to assign a numbering.

```sql
SELECT
  p.PartNumber,
  p.PartValue,
  p2.Parts,
  NewUniqueNumber = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY p2.Parts)
FROM #parts p
JOIN (
    SELECT
      p2.PartNumber,
      STRING_AGG(p2.PartValue, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p2.PartValue) Parts
    FROM #parts p2
    GROUP BY
      p2.PartNumber
) p2 ON p2.PartNumber = p.PartNumber;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5ece61c034872a8a12f58230cf6a5ba3)

Comment: yes correct answer but are there  another solution without using stuff or string aggregate  idea is correct but are there are another solution without using stuff or string aggreagyte if another solution this will be best . this achieve my goal but i need another thing best for performance

Comment: I don't think this is possible any other way unless you use SQLCLR. Why do you think this does not have good performance? You just need an index `(PartNumber, PartValue)`